# Can I share ScalableTarget or ScalingPolicy in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling, aws-sam

I have multiple AWS lambdas defined in my CloudFormation template. I want to define scaling for ProvisionedConcurrency for all of them, say to have minimum 1 provisioned lambda and maximum 4.

Then I have scaling config for one lambda that looks like this:

```
HelloWorldScalingTarget:
  Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
  Properties:
    MaxCapacity: 4
    MinCapacity: 1
    ResourceId: !Sub function:${HelloWorld}:live
    RoleARN: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/aws-service-role/lambda.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_Lambda
    ScalableDimension: lambda:function:ProvisionedConcurrency
    ServiceNamespace: lambda

HelloWorldScalingPolicy:
  Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyName: utilization
    PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
    ScalingTargetId: !Ref HelloWorldScalingTarget
    TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration:
      TargetValue: 0.8
      PredefinedMetricSpecification:
        PredefinedMetricType: LambdaProvisionedConcurrencyUtilization
```

The problem is I need to reference each lambda by name and have separate `ScalableTarget` and `ScalingPolicy` for each lambda. But `ScalingPolicy` is identical for all lambdas.

Is there any way to remove this duplication and share `ScalingPolicy` between lambdas (or `ScalableTarget`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically there is no way to do that. Lambda doesn't represent single instance, it represents a layer that is able to spawn up multiple instances to run your function based on the requests coming to your lambda.

As each lambda can have different properties, like Runtime and memory, The scaling policy for each lambda will affect the instances it only creates. which makes sharing the scaling policy between multiple lambdas is not realistic as the value of utilization will be different for each lambda based on its properties.